# OpenResty POST issue

Tags: http, post, lua, openresty

When having a page that accepts a POST request and running it via jQuery, I get an OpenResty error:

> `25031#0: *237 client sent invalid method while reading client
>   pipelined request line, client: <snip>, server: <snip>, request:
>   "name=&gamemode=&plugname=&port="`

I'm not sure why. If you need any more information, just ask.

Comment: How is this related to Lua?

Comment: Because OpenResty uses Lua.

Answer (score 0):

First, I agree with lhf that is not related to Lua.

Possibly this page has relevant info 
https://github.com/openresty/ngx_openresty/issues/32

Hint - use Google:-)

Comment: Given that it might have a Lua solution, it's certainly related to it. And I've already used all the solutions on Google else I wouldn't of come to Stack Overflow about it.

Comment: Please, provide more details in this case.How did you try to solve the problem? How do you manage POST request?